# How to forward all requests from one port to another with nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to be able to visit `https://localhost:888/` in my browser and have it behave identically as if I had accessed `https://localhost:999/`

How can I do that?

I tried adding

```
server {
    listen   888;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:999;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
}
```

to a new file `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/default`, but I can't access any webpage at `localhost:888` (even though localhost:999 responds fine)

I am using homebrew (`brew install nginx`) version of nginx

Comment: What does "can't access" mean? What is the exact error message?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen same error as visiting http://hallalaopsupaus.com, cannot find the server

Comment: The domain doesn't have proper DNS records.

Comment: @tero "localhost" doesnt have proper dns records??

Comment: If you get the same error `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`, it means that the domain you are accessing does not have proper DNS records.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen it just says "Safari cannot find the server"